# Imported references not found

Tags: pycharm

I am having an issue with the `django` and `rest_framework` packages not successfully being imported into PyCharm Professional.

In the project preferences, I have the Django support enabled and the project root, settings file, and manage file properly set. I have the project interpreter using a Virtualenv environment that Pycharm created when I created the project. The project interpreter has all of the packages defined in the `requirements.txt.` installed.

[image]

In most Python files in my project, I am noticing that some of the `rest_framework` packages can be imported, but others cannot be for no apparent reason. For example, the import `from rest_framework.views import APIView` is able to import properly, but `from django.http import HttpResponse` does not import properly and shows `Unresolved reference 'HttpResponse'`.
[image]

I notice that the reference to `django.http` can be resolved, so I am not sure why the reference to `HttpResponse` cannot be found.

[image]

**I have tried the following to fix the issue:**

1. Invalidate caches and restart the IDE.
2. Removing the virtual environment, creating a new one, and restarting the IDE.
3. Delete the `.idea` file and re-import the project.

I am really lost as to what to try next. The main benefit to using PyCharm is the IntelliSense features and these do not work properly with all packages not being imported properly. Any recommendations are greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `__init__.py` from **Preferences | File type auto-detected by file content | File name patterns**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That solved my issue